# Process loop over multiple file sets

Tags: shell

In order to simplify my work I usually do this:

```
   for FILE in ./*.txt; 
   do ID=`echo ${FILE} | sed 's/^.*\///'`; 
   bin/Tool ${FILE} > ${ID}_output.txt; 
   done
```

Hence process loops over all *.txt files.

Now I have two file groups - my Tool uses two inputs (-a & -b). Is there any command to run Tool for every FILE_A over every FILE_B and name the output file as a combination of both them?

I imagine it should look like something like this:

```
  for  FILE_A in ./filesA/*.txt; 
  do for FILE_B in ./filesB/*.txt; 
  bin/Tool -a ${FILE_A} -b ${FILE_B} > output.txt; 
  done
```

So the process would run number of *.txt in filesA over number of *.txt in filesB.
And also the naming issue which I even don't know where to put in...

Hope it is clear what I am asking. Never had to do such task before and a command line would be really helpful.

Looking forward!

Comment: Although many people like *writing* one-liners, few people want to *read* them.

Comment: looks like all you're missing is the `do` and `done` for the inner loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NEWNAME="${FILE_A##*/}_${FILE_B##*/}_output.txt"
```

Comment: You already have that. Just remember that you need a `do` for each `for`.

Comment: Is this one ok?:
for  FILE_A in ./filesA/*.txt;
do ID=`echo ${FILE_A} | sed 's/^.*\///'`;
for FILE_B in ./filesB/*.txt;
do ID2=`echo ${FILE_B} | sed 's/^.*\///'`;
bin/Tool -a ${FILE_A} -b ${FILE_B} > ${ID}_${ID2}_output.txt;
done;
done

Comment: As long as you don't have spaces, sure.